# Incorporating daily strength exercises in an active lifestyle

Tags: workout-routines, strength-training

I am a dancer, which means that I get a high intensity cardio and leg workout >=2 times a week, 3hrs each. However, I get almost no upper body strength training. I also have pretty much no time (and, lets be honest, no desire) to perform full strength workouts.

Would it be possible to incorporate frequent mini workouts, e.g. pushups, planks, etc., in my daily routine without the need to warm up or change into gym clothes? What would I need to keep in mind to avoid muscle imbalance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's so cool you're a dancer!

I am a huge proponent of daily pushups. I love pushups for upper body strength training because they are simple, functional, and keep you in touch with how well you can handle your own body weight. I've found that having a set number of pushups to complete everyday is really easy to get done, and that even when I'm tired or traveling, I always get it in. It takes just a couple of minutes, and no warm-up needed!

A common compensation is to arch your back, so keep your abdominals engaged to maintain a neutral spine. Keep your elbows tucked close to your sides. You should be lowering yourself until your elbows make a right angle and your chest is just about to the floor. If you add too many reps at once, you'll notice you'll start relying heavily on your dominant arm. If you find yourself compensating, stop adding reps and correct your form.

These famously hit your chest and triceps, but I've seen results in my biceps, too. Being able to do 25-50+ pushups with proper form will build upper body strength and enable you to do other exercises, as well (i.e., doing pushups consistently will help get you to pull-ups).

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your description of the pushups. I think you're talking about something called a "narrow" pushup? And the back arching - is this just to make sure that my hips don't sag while going up?

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible to incorporate frequent mini workouts, e.g.
> pushups, planks, etc., in my daily routine without the need to warm up
> or change into gym clothes?

Yes, this is a common practice.

> What would I need to keep in mind to avoid muscle imbalance?

If your concerns are about injury or otherwise causing yourself harm, then nothing, there's no risk of any harm there.

Comment: Injury is one part of it, yes, but I just wanted to make sure I do this correctly. I've heard that people who do daily pushups _only_ can get muscle imbalance which causes bad posture.

Comment: I'd recommend not listening to those people who think that push-ups will cause bad posture. It's exercise. It's all health promoting, and it's very, very difficult to do it so incorrectly that it has a net detrimental effect.